# Как можно сделать так, чтобы выполнялись параллельно две функции?

Tags: c++

А не так, чтобы сначала одна функция выполнилась, а потом другая. Возможно ли такое реализовать? Подскажите литературу с примерами на эту тему.

Comment: Одну функцию выполнять в одном треде, а другую в другом, не?

Comment: Можно, если одну функцию запустить на одном ядре, а вторую на другом ядре.  
P.S. Все ответы предлагающие потоки без гарантированного распределения по ядрам процессора изначально неверны :)  
P.P.S а еще можно одну функцию на одном компьютере запустить, а вторую на другом.

Comment: @karmadro4, а как можно это реализовать?
ЗЫ. Посоветуй литературу.

Comment: @NameX это называется параллельное программирование

Comment: @ReinRaus, не доверяете услугам планировщика? :-)

Comment: @karmadro4, он может и на одно ядро их распределить, а в таком случае они будут выполнятся не параллельно, а промежутками 50 мкс процессорного времени.

Comment: @ReinRaus, волноваться об этом - преждевременная оптимизация.

Comment: @karmadro4, так ведь прочитайте вопрос: они должны выполнятся параллельно. Ответ без гарантии использования разных ядер неверен, потому что в этом случае процессы могут попасть на одно ядро и будут работать не по-настоящему параллельно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, наш уровень абстракции полагает треды выполняющимися параллельно. Хотя любой физик знает, что они несинхронны даже на идеально идентичных процессорах. То же самое с "ядрами".

Comment: Так "параллельно" или "сначала одна, а потом другая"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начинай копать с CreateThread. Сначала почитай документацию потом поищи примеры в сети.

Answer (score 4):

Еще есть кросс-платформенная библиотека [`boost/thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Answer (score 1):

На парах по параллельному программированию мы это реализовывали через MPI.

[Ссылка](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/).

Answer (score 1):

Для *nix начните с **man 7 pthreads**, посмотрите **man pthread_create**, для управления привязкой процессов/потоков к CPU начните с **man sched_setaffinity**.

В любом случае ключевое слово - поток (thread).